# What speed gain am I changing if I optimize for size (z) instead of speed (3)?

Tags: optimization, rust, compilation, llvm, rust-cargo

I read both:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#opt-level
- https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#optimize-for-size

What I don't understand is which speed gain I'm changing if I use:

```
[profile.release]
opt-level = "z"
```

instead of:

```
[profile.release]
opt-level = 3
```

- Is it right that today `opt-level = 3` is the best setting (for `opt-level` section) for runtime speed?
- If I instead use `opt-level = "z"` I'm decreasing runtime performance, right?

I'm not interested in building/compiling speed.

Comment: If you choose "z", you aren't sacrificing all optimizations but you may lose some due to the fact that you want a smaller binary.

Comment: The only true answer is to profile *your* code on *your* systems with *your* data under both settings. Then you will know which is faster. If you don't have a way to profile performance changes to your application, performance is likely not a primary concern at this point in time.

Comment: Note that the marginal utility of more optimizations drops at higher levels. Going from `-O2` to `-O3` will not usually improve performance as much as going from `-O1` to `-O2`, and could even be a regression. The conventional wisdom used to be that `-O2`, `-Oz` and `-O3` are all roughly equally "good" and you need to profile to determine which is best for your program. It's unusual that `-O3` will be slower than `-O2` but it may not be sufficiently faster to make the additional compile time worthwhile.

Answer (score 8):

**It's complicated.**

The truth of the matter is that a compiler optimization pipeline is largely based on *heuristics*.

A number of optimizations are sure things (such as *strength reduction*), however many heavy lifters (such as *inlining*) are based on a set of heuristics.

The heuristics, of course, are not pulled out of thin air. They have been carefully tuned by the compiler developers based on a sample of programs that is judged representative, and polished based on customer reports.

Still, at the end of the day, they remain *heuristics*, and as a result some programs are faster with `-Oz` than with `-O3`, because a different set of heuristics is used.

Comment: And some programs (actually, a lot, because of inlining) are smaller with `-Os` or `-O1` or `-O2` than with `-Oz`.